# ValueError: Found input tensor cannot be reached given provided output tensors. Please make sure the tensor KerasTensor

Tags: python, keras

ValueError: Found input tensor cannot be reached given provided output tensors. Please make sure the tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='Sec_data'), name='Sec_data', description="created by layer 'Sec_data'") is included in the model inputs when building functional model.

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /Users/zhhh/AstrocyteSegmentation-1/train.ipynb Cell 3 in <cell
> line: 1>()
> ----> 1 GESU_net.train()
>
> File ~/AstrocyteSegmentation-1/GESU_net.py:195, in
> myGESUnet.train(self)
> 192 print('train data size1:', imgs_train.shape)
> 194 print("loading data done")
> --> 195 model = self.get_gesunet()
> 197 model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('Model_GESU.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
> 198 print('Fitting model...')
>
> File ~/AstrocyteSegmentation-1/GESU_net.py:176, in
> myGESUnet.get_gesunet(self)
> 173 conv10t = Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv10t)
> 174 conv10t = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv10t)
> --> 176 modelB = Model(inputs = inputsT, outputs = conv10t)
> 179 Out1= modelA(inputs)
> 180 Out = modelB(Out1)
>
> File
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py:587,
> in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.._method_wrapper(self,
> *args, **kwargs)
> 585 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> 586 try:
> --> 587   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 588 finally:
> 589   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> File
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:147,
> in Functional.**init**(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable,
> **kwargs)
> 144 if tf.compat.v1.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
> 145   if not all([functional_utils.is_input_keras_tensor(t)
> 146               for t in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)]):
> --> 147     inputs, outputs = functional_utils.clone_graph_nodes(inputs, outputs)
> 148 self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
>
> File
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional_utils.py:146,
> in clone_graph_nodes(inputs, outputs)
> 128 def clone_graph_nodes(inputs, outputs):
> 129   """Clone the `Node` between the inputs and output tensors.
> 130
> 131   This function is used to create a new functional model from any intermediate    (...)
> 144     create a new functional model.
> 145   """
> --> 146   nodes_to_clone = find_nodes_by_inputs_and_outputs(inputs, outputs)
> 147   cloned_inputs = []
> 148   cloned_outputs = []
>
> File
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/functional_utils.py:113,
> in find_nodes_by_inputs_and_outputs(inputs, outputs)
> 108     # In case this is the tf.keras.Input node, we have reached the end of the
> 109     # tracing of upstream nodes. Any further tracing will just be an
> 110     # infinite loop. we should raise an error here since we didn't find the
> 111     # input in the user-specified inputs.
> 112     if inbound_node.is_input:
> --> 113       raise ValueError('Found input tensor cannot be reached given provided '
> 114                        'output tensors. Please make sure the tensor {} is '
> 115                        'included in the model inputs when building '
> 116                        'functional model.'.format(kt))
> 117     nodes_to_visit.append(inbound_node)
> 119 # Do a final check and make sure we have reached all the user-specified inputs
>
> ValueError: Found input tensor cannot be reached given provided output
> tensors. Please make sure the tensor
> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128, 3),
> dtype=tf.float32, name='Sec_data'), name='Sec_data',
> description="created by layer 'Sec_data'") is included in the model
> inputs when building functional model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but I can include enough code to show how I am running into this error since OP seems to have left that out.

```
    price_sheet_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=(MAX_PACKAGES, 2 * N_PRODUCTS + 1), name="price_sheet_in")
    job_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(103), name="job_in")
    studio_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(15), name="studio_in")
    # non_hist_model is a sales prediction for this job without factoring in this user's history
    this_job_estimate = non_hist_model([price_sheet_in, job_inputs, studio_inputs])
    hist_price_sheets = tf.keras.Input(shape=(HIST_JOB_COUNT, MAX_PACKAGES, 2 * N_PRODUCTS + 1),
                                       name="hist_price_sheets")
    hist_job_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(HIST_JOB_COUNT, 103), name="hist_job_in")
    hist_revenues = tf.keras.Input(shape=(HIST_JOB_COUNT), name="hist_revenues_in")
    expanded_studio_input = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(HIST_JOB_COUNT, name="studio_repeat")(studio_inputs)

    flatish_hist_price_sheets = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((HIST_JOB_COUNT, MAX_PACKAGES * (2 * N_PRODUCTS + 1)),
                                                        name="flattenish")(hist_price_sheets)
    # stupid_non_hist_model is a version of non_hist_model that takes a flattened input as required by TimeDistributed
    hist_estimates = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
        stupid_non_hist_model, name="hist_predictions"
    )([flatish_hist_price_sheets, hist_job_inputs, expanded_studio_input])
    hist_estimates = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(hist_estimates)
    # get a percent error for each estimate
    hist_comparisons = tf.keras.layers.Subtract(name="hist_pred_minus_true")([hist_estimates, hist_revenues])
    hist_revenues = tf.math.add(hist_revenues, tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
    hist_comparisons = tf.math.divide(hist_comparisons, hist_revenues)
    hist_mod = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="hist_mod", activation="softplus")(hist_comparisons)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([hist_mod, this_job_estimate])
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[price_sheet_in, job_inputs, studio_inputs,
                                   hist_price_sheets, hist_job_inputs, hist_revenues],
                           outputs=[out], name="full_model")
```

hist_revenues is the input that is giving me the error. This model uses a submodel that takes some inputs and predicts an output. When used IRL we have historical data for the specific user so I'm attempting to create some sort of modifier based on the difference between the submodel's predictions and the ground truth to be used on subsequent predictions.

The error seems to be implying that the output is not dependent on the input but that's just not true. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I immediately fixed it myself. The issue is that you cannot re-use a variable name if that variable is a keras input.

```
hist_revenues = tf.keras.Input(shape=(HIST_JOB_COUNT), name="hist_revenues_in")
hist_revenues = tf.math.add(hist_revenues, tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
```

becomes

```
hist_revenues = tf.keras.Input(shape=(HIST_JOB_COUNT), name="hist_revenues_in")
nonzero_hist_revenues = tf.math.add(hist_revenues, tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
```

and the issue is resolved.